# How to solve "control reaches end of non-void function" warning?

Tags: c, function

so in this function of mine, it is spitting out this warning: "carboard.c:79:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]". Program runs fine, but i just want it to compile cleanly.

here is the code of the function:

```
int loadMainMenu()
{
    char choice[LINE + EXTRA_SPACES];
    Boolean menu = TRUE;

    printf("\nWelcome to Car Board\n");
    printf("--------------------\n");
    printf("1. Play Game\n");
    printf("2. Show Student's Information\n");
    printf("3. Quit\n");
    printf("\n");
    printf("Please Enter Your Choice:\n");


    do
    {
        int input;

        fgets(choice, LINE + EXTRA_SPACES, stdin);

        if (choice[strlen(choice) - 1] != '\n')
        {
            printf("BUFFER OVERFLOW!\n\n");
            readRestOfLine();
        }

        choice[strlen(choice) - 1] = 0;


        input = atoi(choice);

        switch(input)
        {
            case 1: playGame();
                break;
            case 2: showStudentInformation();
                    loadMainMenu();
                break;
            case 3: 
                printf("Bye bye! \n");
                return EXIT_SUCCESS;
                break;
            default: printf("Invalid input\n");
                     loadMainMenu();
                break;    
        }
    }while(menu);
}
```

Comment: If you want an infinite loop, you don't need a separate variable, `while (true)` works just as well as `while (menu)`, and probably confuses the compiler less.

Comment: Famous last words: "Program runs fine" - If I had one cent each time I hear this ... Use a `void` function and best qualify as `_Noreturn` if you really don't want to return.

Comment: It's telling you the function is defined to return a value. But some paths in your function do not return a value. Add a `return 0` at the end of the function or whatever it is supposed to return by default.

Comment: @kaylum: Which path reaches the end of the function? I don't see one.

Comment: Or make its `return` type `void`.

Comment: And use the C standard boolean type, no homebrew types.

Comment: @Olaf What? That case explicitly `return`s, it does not reach the `}` at the end of the function.

Comment: @EOF Just addressing the warning and not the logic. The warning is the actual OP question. But yes, you are right that the logic does not actually allow the function to reach the end. But the compiler doesn't work that out and hence the warning. So yes, the logic needs to be fixed but it's likely that a `return` is also needed at the end.

Comment: @kaylum: I'd say that this is not a correctness bug, it's non-idiomatic style which confuses the compiler.

Comment: @EOF: Ok, I see your point now. I think the compiler is not _that_ smart.

Comment: `do { } while(menu);` could simply be `for(;;) { }` and the compiler warning would go away. But the bigger issue is that the function calls itself recursively. Which means that you need to press 3 multiple times (depending how many 2's and defaults were executed) to actually get out of the function.

Answer (score 2):

You need to have a return statement in your code. Since your function is returning an integer you must have something likek `return x;` where x is an integer or you can declare function void.

Comment: The code, as posted, never reaches the end of the function.

Comment: Edited alternative declaration for that.

Comment: Read the comments above!

Answer (score 1):

The compiler is not that smart to figure out the `do ... while` never terminates.

To fix this, first ensure the loop **cannot** end by making it guaranted infinite using a constant:

```
do {

} while ( true );
```

If that doesn't work, try

```
while ( true ) {
    ...
}
```

The compiler might require a specific pattern ( `for ( ; ; )` might also be worth a try; it is also a matter of personal preference).

If that still does not work, just `return 0;` after the loop above. That might be optimised away, so no extra code at best. At worst, you have to live with some dangling code.

An alternative would be to temporarily disable the warning using a pragma. **That should really only be the last ressort**.